# What are the differences in an API for HTTP requests vs HTTPS requests?

Tags: node.js, http, https

I created a simple REST API in Node JS to use simple HTTP requests to handle the get / post requests for a database.

How different is an API for HTTPS vs HTTP requests?

I would like to use HTTPS as its more secure, and opens the door for geolocation functionality. But, all my experience with APIs have been limited to dealing with HTTP requests.

Comment: No difference. Both implement the HTTP verbs and transfer the data similarly. HTTPS is encrypted but you generally don't deal with that in your code. Consuming the API is not reliant on the encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Under my experience there hasn't been much change, if you search on youtube there are some great videos and the extras, there are some slight differences but it doesn't change too much